# How to make indicator for navigations buttons like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

What is the fastest and best option to make a navigation button like this?
Can I use TextButtons or BottomNavigationBar?
[Navigation buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IujiF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're speaking of `TabBar`.

Here's the official documentation with examples:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot :) I haven't found the name and documentation for that